# How can I sort a vector of boolean vectors in this way? ('ranking analysis')

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic, ranking

We need to sort a large number of vectors (an array of arrays) containing only true and false (1's and 0's), all the same size.
We have the rules that 1 + 1 = 1 (true + true = true) and 1 + 0 = 1 and 0 + 0 = 0.

- The first vector is the one with the most 1's.
- The second vector is the one which brings more 1's in addition to the ones we already had in the first vector.
- The third vector is the one which brings more 1's in addition to the ones we already had in the previous 2 vectors.
- And so on.

For example, let's say we have these 3 vectors:

```
a. (0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
b. (1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
c. (0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
```

The first one in our sort is b because it has the most 1's.
The next one is a. Even though c has more 1's than a, a has more 1's in addition to the 1's we had in b.
By now, the sum of a + b is (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), so the last one is c because, it brings nothing new to the sorting.

If two vectors brings the same number of extra 1's, the order of them doesn't really matter. I believe there are multiple possible results for this kind of sorting and they are all as good.

We call this a 'ranking analysis' here, but we don't have a clear term for this kind of sort and google doesn't yield very useful info on it.

The easiest method is to just take them one by one with an O(n^2). However, we are working with big data and we already have a software for this which is too slow, so we need something really optimized.

How can we achieve this? Programming language doesn't matter, we can use anything. Can this be parallelized (run it on multiple CPU's to speed up the process)? Any sources or ideas are welcome.

Edit: I checked; apparently we have a case where the length of these vectors is 103, so they can be longer than 64 slots.

Comment: This O(n^2) approach can be optimised quite a bit though, so perhaps that is an avenue worth exploring. It is not immediately clear to me if you can do much better, since the ordering depends on the ones you've already set, so anything like quicksort is out of the question. I.e. you don't satisfy a very basic property that most fast sorting algorithms rely on.

Comment: We will explore that idea further. At the moment any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How long are these vectors?

Comment: They range from about 10 to 50, based on category. (but they are all the same length in their category).
The number of vectors is in the millions.

Comment: Then these operations themselves can easily be optmised, even if you have to use 2 64bit integers to store one, as your edit mentions. Nevertheless, the massive number of vectors may be a problem for any O(n^2) approach. Given the number of vectors, it may actually be beneficial to parallelise the search at each step of the algorithm, if a better approach can not be found.